# Python pandas: set row and col to zeros if element is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve the following python interview questions using Pandas:

Given a m x n matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in-place.

Here are some examples:

```
# Example 1
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]  # input
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]  # output

# Example 2
[[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1, 5]]  # input
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 5, 0], [0, 3, 1, 0]]  # output
```

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
def solution(mat):
    """Brute force - O(n**2)"""
    cols = []
    for i, row in enumerate(mat):
        for j, item in enumerate(row):
            if item == 0:
                mat[i] = [0] * len(row)
                cols.append(j)

    for i, _ in enumerate(mat):
        for j in cols:
            mat[i][j] = 0
```

Is there a better way to do this using Pandas?

Comment: you  don't use pandas

Comment: @run-out I said I don't see pandas in question. If someone has problem with pandas then it should try to do something in pandas - at least he create DataFrame. Beside it is place for comment, and I don't have to give alternative solution. Place for solution is below in answers.

Comment: @run-out and what this means for you ? for me it means "You don't use pandas, I don't see pandas in your question."

Comment: `pandas` can indeed used here, but since you are dealing with matrix, I would go for `numpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `.eq`, `.any` and `.loc`

We can check where our dataframe is equal to 0 with `.eq`.
Then we check with `.any` over `axis=1` and `axis=0` to select rows and column which contain **any** 0's.

Finally we set those rows/columns to `0` with `.loc`;

```
# Example dataframe
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  1  1
```

```
m1 = df.eq(0).any(axis=1)
m2 = df.eq(0).any(axis=0)

df.loc[m1] = 0
df.loc[:, m2] = 0
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  1
1  0  0  0
2  1  0  1
```

---

**Test 2** on second example:

```
# Example dataframe #2
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  2  0
1  3  4  5  2
2  1  3  1  5

m1 = df.eq(0).any(axis=1)
m2 = df.eq(0).any(axis=0)

df.loc[m1] = 0
df.loc[:, m2] = 0
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  4  5  0
2  0  3  1  0
```

Comment: check your variable 'm' df.loc[m] =0

Answer (score 4):

This solution using numpy broadcast to create the whole dataframe mask and pandas `where` to set 0

```
m = df.ne(0).all(0).values[None,:] * df.ne(0).all(1).values[:,None]

Out[834]:
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])

df.where(m, 0)
Out[835]:
   0  1  2
0  1  0  1
1  0  0  0
2  1  0  1
```

---

```
m1 = df1.ne(0).all(0).values[None,:] * df1.ne(0).all(1).values[:,None]

Out[838]:
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False]])

df1.where(m1, 0)

Out[839]:
   a  b  c  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  4  5  0
2  0  3  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not in one step but it is what I get. It is shorter and cleaner then using `for`-loops

You can get rows and columns with any zero

```
rows = (df == 0).any(1)
cols = (df == 0).any(0)
```

and then you can set zero in rows and columns

```
df.loc[rows,:] = 0
df.loc[:,cols] = 0
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
#df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1, 5]])

rows = (df == 0).any(1)
cols = (df == 0).any(0)

df.loc[rows,:] = 0
df.loc[:,cols] = 0

print(df)
```

Comment: This is almost a one one copy of my answer, but then you just `==` instead of  `.eq`?

Comment: I was working on solution at the same time and get similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with matrices, I would use `numpy` rather than `pandas`. You already have good answers with `pandas`, so I propose one with `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

ia = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
ib = [[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1, 5]]

a = np.array(ia)
b = np.array(ib)

def funczero(x):
    idxs = np.argwhere(x == 0) #find indexes where the matrix element is 0
    for i in idxs:
        x[i[0],:] = 0 #setting all row elements to 0 
        x[:,i[1]] = 0 #setting all column elements to 0
```

`funczero` works in place, so you call for example `funczero(a)` and `a` is modified.